# How to get events instantly using SSE?

Tags: php, server-sent-events, event-stream

I'm currently trying to use Server-Sent Events using PHP, but they are not firing instantly on the browser.

Here is my code:

```php
<?php
    
    // Headers must be processed line by line.
    header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
    header('X-Accel-Buffering: no');
    while(true)
    {
    
        // Set data line
        echo "event: server-time";
        echo "data: " . date( 'G:H:s', time() );
        //echo str_repeat(" ", 4096);
    
        ob_end_flush();     // Strange behaviour, will not work
        flush();            // Unless both are called !
    
        // Wait one second.
        sleep(1);

}
```

While it works, it seems like there is a minimum size for the buffer to flush and send data to the browser. In fact, if I uncomment the `str_repeat` line, I get almost instantaneous events (as in, one every second). However, if I keep it commented, the browser keeps loading for around 2 minutes, before sending all the data from the past 2 minutes.

I've looked around on Stack Overflow but I couldn't find an answer that works within all of them.

Here are some infos from `phpinfo()` that I find useful in this context, don't hesitate to ask for more:

## PHPINFO

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Server API | FPM/FastCGI |
| PHP Version | 7.4.30 |
| BZip2 Support | Enabled |
| Registered PHP Streams | https, ftps, compress.zlib, compress.bzip2, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, phar, ssh2.shell, ssh2.exec, ssh2.tunnel, ssh2.scp, ssh2.sftp, zip |
| Registered Stream Socket Transports | tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, tls, tlsv1.0, tlsv1.1, tlsv1.2, tlsv1.3 |
| Registered Stream Filters | zlib.*, bzip2.*, convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk, mcrypt.*, mdecrypt.*, http.* |
| Stream Wrapper support | compress.bzip2:// |
| Stream Filter support | bzip2.decompress, bzip2.compress |
| BZip2 Version | 1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010 |
| output_buffering | no value |
| output_encoding | no value |
| output_handler | no value |
| zlib.output_compression | Off |
| zlib.output_compression_level | -1 |
| zlib.output_handler | no value |

Answer (score 2):

`ob_flush()` is for PHP's own buffer (which is why it comes first), and `flush()` is supposed to flush the web server cache. So your code is correct. I think the problem you are having is due to you using "FPM/FastCGI"

I found [this comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php#125306) in the manual:

> If you want to make flush work when using php-fpm from Apache httpd with mod_proxy_fcgi, since 2.4.31 you can append flushpackets=on to enable flushing,

This page has a few suggestions: https://serverfault.com/q/488767  (Note that they are all older than the above manual comment.)

Or, if not bound to FastCGI, another solution would be to switch to Apache's PHP module, where `flush()` definitely works.

Answer (score -2):

I dont know why people use while loop in SSE codes.
Doesnt it hang your browsers?.

```
<?php
    // Headers must be processed line by line.
    header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
    header('X-Accel-Buffering: no');
    // Set data line
    $events = "";
    $events .= "event: server-time\ndata: " . date('G:H:s', time()) . "\n\n"

    //Append other events with logic

    echo $event;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32545666)